# In Makefiles, how to display percentage of compilation followed by compiler's warnings/errors

Tags: gcc, makefile, cursor-position

This is a bit tricky...

I want my Makefile to display progression percentage of my compilation. This is easy as long as I use tput or escaped sequences to move my cursor to modify my percentage.

But if a warning appears, the next warning will be on the previous one and so on...

How can I do something like that ?

I've already found some ideas like storing cursor position inside a variable, but I failed.
I've thought about redirect gcc's (or clang's idc) output to a variable but it failed too.

I can output the cursor position with : `echo -en "\033[6n" ; read -sdR CURPOS ; CURPOS=$${CURPOS#*[} ; echo "$${CURPOS}"` but I cannot use `$(shell ..)` because it just infinit loop (I guess) so `$(eval VAR = $(shell echo ..))` is impossible.

Maybe I'm looking the problem at the wrong side ?

I'm really stuck tbh so thank for your help

EDIT:

```
224 all : $(TARGET)
225     if [[ ! '$(FILE_TODO)' == '0' ]]; then echo -e $(RPOS)$(ENDRASE)Done\n$(DEBUG_COLOR)[Linkage]$(NORMAL) - Done'; fi
226     $(ECHO) '$(DEBUG_MODE_MSG) : $(if $(ISXX),$(CXXFLAGS),$(CFLAGS))'
227                                                                                   
228 $(TARGET) : $(OBJFILES)
230     $(CC) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS) $(LINKAGE) $(if $(UNITARY),--coverage,) $^
231 
232 display :
233     $(eval OBJ_NBR := $(shell if [[ -d '$(OBJDIR)' ]]; then find $(OBJDIR) -type f -name \*$(OBJEXT); fi))
234     $(eval OBJ_NBR := $(shell echo -n "$$(($(words $(OBJ_NBR))))"))
235     $(eval FILE_TODO := $(shell echo "$$(($(SRC_NBR)-$(OBJ_NBR)))"))
236     if [[ ! '$(FILE_TODO)' == '0' ]]; then echo -en '$(DEBUG_COLOR)[Compilation]$(NORMAL) - $(SPOS)'; fi
237 
238 $(OBJDIR)/%$(OBJEXT) : %$(SRCEXT) | display
239     $(eval I := $(shell echo -n "$$(($(I)+1))"))
240     $(eval PERCENT := $(shell echo "$$((100*$(I)/$(FILE_TODO)))"))
241     $(ECHO) '$(RPOS)$(ENDRASE)$(PERCENT)% ($<)' 
242     $(MKDIR) $(@D) $(patsubst $(OBJDIR)%,$(DEPDIR)%,$(@D))                             
243     $(CC) -c $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $(DEPFLAGS) $(if $(ISXX),$(CXXFLAGS),$(CFLAGS)) $(CPPFLAGS) $(WARNING) $(WNO) $(COMPILATION) $<
```

Comment: If you think calculating and displaying an accurate percentage isn't hard, this should be a breeze. Percent of what? Display how? Show us what you have so far.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's not clear what you want this process to print when the compiler gives warnings.

Comment: I'm not sure that integrating the percentage output into Makefile is the right logic. Consider other alternatives/build systems, which provides this functionality

Comment: @dash-o I canno't use other build systems as long as I'm studient.

Comment: How do you plan to measure 'percentage'. The number of files to compile depends on the number of source files modified ?

Comment: @dash-o I've finally done it, I can now display correctly. And I'm now against this exact problem xD I'm currently searching if there is any way to do it

Comment: The logic in the question is based on counting files. However, make will usually skip rebuilding of up-to-date objects (based on timestamp). Counting '.o' could be very different number of compile tasks. The extra dependency on pseudo-target 'display' will disable the (usually very desired) feature of incremental build. Also, what will happen on non-interactive build ? the output will become hard to read

Comment: I would comment that this is a excellent question - I think it's worth submitting a feature request to feature request to the GNU make team.

Comment: @dash-o What do you mean ? You think that I should show my Makefile on feature request or something like that on github ? I'm sorry for my lack of engish

Comment: @dash-o Yep, GNU could provide a couple of variables expandable in the target's recipe with the total number of targets to build and the current target number.

Comment: @dash-o idk if you didn't see my question or ? I allow my self to ping you back

Comment: I think that enhancement request to the '-n' output that will capture the regenerated items will work. Asking for additional variables is likely to get lot of question, and will be hard to justified.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to injecting rules, targets in Makefile, which have the the potential to have negative impact on the build process, consider a 'wrapper' tool that will work around the make program.

1. Query make for number of require build steps
2. Execute make, periodically checking for  remaining steps, showing %-age.

In general, assuming the make process is simple (e.g., no recursion), executing 'make -n' will be fast, provide (relatively) accurate result, and will not have negative impact on the build process

Comment: I can count how many file I've to recompile thanks to "$(MAKE) count", a rule that I've create to count without compiling it by a `ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS), count)`.

The problem is the variable isn't passed from the sub make to the current make.

I still can count in the current Make and compile in a sub Make but it is weird... and I don't really know if it will works anyway

Comment: In you wrapper bash script `TODO_COUNT=$(make count)` will give you a variable that you can pass, if needed, to future make calls: `make TODO_COUNT=$TODO_COUNT ...`

Comment: I didn't understand how to do what you said so i've done it defferently by using an echo inside a $(shell) call

Answer (score 0):

Well, everything seems to be working even if it is dirty

```
238 count : $(OBJFILES)
239     $(ECHO) $(COUNTING)
240 
241 display :
242 ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS), count)
243     $(eval FILE_TODO := $(shell $(MAKE) count))                                                                                                                                            
244     if [[ ! '$(FILE_TODO)' == '' ]]; then echo -e '$(DEBUG_COLOR)[Compilation]$(NORMAL) - $(SPOS)'; fi
245     echo -en "\033[6n" ; read -sdR CURPOS ; echo $${CURPOS#*[} > .curs_pos.tmp
246 endif
247 
248 CURPOS          =   $(shell cat .curs_pos.tmp)
249 
250 $(OBJDIR)/%$(OBJEXT) : %$(SRCEXT) | display
251 ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS), count)
252     $(eval I := $(shell echo -n "$$(($(I)+1))"))
253     $(eval PERCENT := $(shell printf %.2f "$$((10000*$(I)-1)/($(FILE_TODO))))e-2"))
254     $(ECHO) -n '$(HIDECURS)$(RPOS)$(ENDRASE)$(PERCENT)% ($<)'
255     $(eval CURPOS = $(shell cat .curs_pos.tmp))
256     $(ECHO) -n "\033[$(CURPOS)H$(SHOWCURS)"
257     $(MKDIR) $(@D) $(patsubst $(OBJDIR)%,$(DEPDIR)%,$(@D))
258     $(CC) -c $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $(DEPFLAGS) $(if $(ISXX),$(CXXFLAGS),$(CFLAGS)) $(CPPFLAGS) $(WARNING) $(WNO) $(COMPILATION) $<
259     echo -en "\033[6n" ; read -sdR CURPOS ; echo $${CURPOS#*[} > .curs_pos.tmp
260 else
261     $(eval COUNTING = $(shell echo -n "$$(($(COUNTING)+1))"))
262 endif
```

Thank you, and I'm listening every comment...

Comment: Recommend looking into https://askubuntu.com/questions/930994/how-to-make-a-progress-bar-work-in-zenity it provides a framework for creating a progress bar from command line utilities. Also: https://help.gnome.org/users/zenity/3.24/progress.html.en